# method that gets a class and calls its main function

Tags: java

I want to write a method that gets a class and an Array of strings and call the main method of the class with the array given.

Something like this:

```
public static void ExecuteMain(DefaultClass cls, String[] args){
    cls.main(args);
}
```

The problem is, I want to do it with several classes, and can't pass the exact class as the type. I also can't have all of the other classes implement a default interface or class because it should be used as a tester for my classmates with the same class names.

Is there any way to do it with those restrictions?

Comment: change `DefautClass cls` to `Class<?> cls`, and then do `cls.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class).invoke(null, args);`

Comment: I'm sorry I am pretty new to java and may have not used the right language
I have 2 java files(classes) in my folder, and I want' with my new file to run the other files(named Assignment1 and Assignment2)
which means i have 2 classes named Assignment1 and 2 and those are the classes i want to run

when i tried applying your code, it said
 Error:(114, 21) java: incompatible types: Assignment1 cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<?>

Comment: Please refer to [The Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) trail in Oracle's java tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given below is how you should define the method:

```
public static void executeMain(Class<?> cls, Object[] args) {
    try {
        Object[] param = { args };
        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("main", args.getClass());
        method.invoke(cls, param);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

## Demo

*Assignment1.java:*

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Assignment1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args == null) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to Assignment1");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Arguments to main in Assignment1: " + Arrays.toString(args));
        }
    }
}
```

*Assignment2.java*

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Assignment2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args == null) {
            System.out.println("Welcome to Assignment2");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Arguments to main in Assignment2: " + Arrays.toString(args));
        }
    }
}
```

**Test class:**

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Assignment1.main(null);
        Assignment1.main(new String[] { "Hello", "World" });
        Assignment2.main(null);
        Assignment2.main(new String[] { "Hello", "World" });
        executeMain(Assignment1.class, new String[] { "Good", "Morning" });
        executeMain(Assignment2.class, new String[] { "Good", "Morning" });
    }

    public static void executeMain(Class<?> cls, Object[] args) {
        try {
            Object[] param = { args };
            Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("main", args.getClass());
            method.invoke(cls, param);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Welcome to Assignment1
Arguments to main in Assignment1: [Hello, World]
Welcome to Assignment2
Arguments to main in Assignment2: [Hello, World]
Arguments to main in Assignment1: [Good, Morning]
Arguments to main in Assignment2: [Good, Morning]
```

Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html) to learn more about Java Reflection API.

Comment: Down-voter, it will be helpful if you can leave a comment about why you've disliked the answer. A down-vote without comment is not useful in cases where the answer is correct, has been accepted, and is sufficiently explained.