# How do I run the main method in a different file in Java?

Tags: java, import, program-entry-point

```
package jav;
class PackageDemo
{
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("PackageDemo executed");
    }
}
public class PackageDemoDriver
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PackageDemo boy = new PackageDemo();
        boy.display();
    }
}
```

This is the code for a package.
I will be importing this package into a different file.
The code for that is:

```
package exercise;
import jav.PackageDemoDriver;
class Exe
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {



    }
}
```

What should I fill in the main method to run display(), if it is possible to do so?

Comment: Show the name of the different .java files so we can understand what you have done. It looks like u have 2 classes in the same file, which is wrong.

Comment: That's not how that works. If you want to use `jav` as a library, then its API has to be public. A driver is only for testing or similar. In your exercise, you would then import the `jav` namespace instead of the driver and just instantiate and use the (public) types.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60934322/method-that-gets-a-class-and-calls-its-main-function/60938319#60938319

Comment: jav is just a folder

Comment: Driver is just a name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off your question I assume you want the main function in Exe to essentially run the main function in PackageDemoDriver:

```
public class Exe {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        PackageDemoDriver.main(null);
    }
}
```

I think that'll provide the functionality you're after, if your PackageDemo and PackageDemoDriver are in different classes

Answer (score 1):

You can run static methods as needed

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    PackageDemoDriver.main(args);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
package exercise;
import jav.PackageDemoDriver;

class Exe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PackageDemoDrive.main(args);
    }
}
```